# Error: Could not find truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol from any sources;

Tags: truffle, java

I am working an a blockchain sample project, and I am trying to write a test for my contract and deploy it into **Ganache**. So, I have to add something like this:

```
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
```

But I can not find any file named **DeployedAddressed.sol** in my project directory.

How do I find that? Is **DeployedAddressed.sol** a built-in truffle library or do I have to install it separately?

Answer (score 0):

This file is ***generated*** when you using truffle as a tool to deploy your contract into ganache. File **DeployedAddresses.sol** is containing  addresses of deployed contracts in ganache or your contracts.
 So before any action, ***be sure your contracts are deployed*** to fill **DeployedAddresses.sol**. After deploying related contract, ***DeployedAddresses.sol*** will be accessible.